# How to remove horizontal space between divs that contain fixed size svg elements?

Tags: html, css, svg

I need my divs to take up the available horizontal space (if they fit), and they need to be centered. My code so far gives me horizontal spaces between my divs. How can I remove it?

Here is my html/css so far

```css
body {
  line-height: 0;
}

#outer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
        <div class="inner">
          <svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
          <svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
          <svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I realize `text-align: center` may not be the best way to center the divs, but it's the only thing that has worked so far.

**Edit:** The accepted answer fixes the centering problem. The horizontal space problem is solved by setting `font-size: 0`.

Comment: another way is to use flex layout, but what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css rules to your outer div:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

try the this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/drctjt1c/)

You can learn more about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)